# Setting focus in textfields

Tags: iphone

I have 3 textfields, which can hold at most one character. If a character is entered in first textfield, then the focus should automatically shift to the second and so on.

For this, I used textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
Going by this, I could check the length of my textfield and assign first responder status to the next textfield.
When i type a character in the first textfield, the character is displayed in the textfield, but the focus doesn't automatically shift to the next textfield. It shifts only when I enter the next alphabet, where it tries to check the condition, and thereby it fails, and then only the focus shifts to the next textfield.
IS there anyway where, the focus should be shifted to the second, just after the first character is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the length of the `replacementString` parameter instead of that of the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
```

on it. You can check that it can become first responder with the method

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
```